# Add an edge to a planar graph and preserving the planarity

Tags: graphs, trees, planar-graphs

I've already posted in the Math StackExchange section, but nobody answered.

I’m wondering if, given a planar graph $G$ And two vertices $v,u$, is there an efficient algorithm to know if adding the edge $(v,u)$ to $G$ makes the graph non-planar?

I’m thinking something that runs in $O(1)$ for every query, even if it needs some pre-computation it’s fine.

Comment: It's a good question.  It was cross-posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4458003/14578.  I realize this may not be intuitive, but we ask that you not cross-post your question.  Rather, we'd prefer that you pick one site where you want your question to appear.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [A Dynamic Data Structure for Planar Graph Embedding](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/74258/B37-ACT_83.pdf)

Comment: Sorry for crossposting, I can remove the other one since there is nothing interesting, while here you gave me a really interesting reference

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I would prefer if you picked one site and deleted the other copies, so we don't have multiple copies open on multiple sites.